# Create a smaller list based off of a list when a certain condition is met in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a list of names in column A. In column B I have "Pass" or "Fail". What formula could I use in Column C that will condense the list in Column A to reflect only the names of the people who have a corresponding "Fail" in Column B.  Here is a quick example:

Column A                 Column B              Desired Result for Column C
Joe                       Pass                          Steve
Steve                     Fail                          Bob
Bob                       Fail                          Al
Gary                      Pass
Al                        Fail
Will                      Pass
Nathan                    Pass

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me try that again.

Comment: Column A: Joe, Steve, Bob, Al, Gary, Will, Nathan.

Comment: Column B: Pass, Fail, Fail, Pass, Fail, Pass, Pass.

Comment: Desired Result for Column C: Steve, Bob, Gary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use a "helper" column.

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="Fail",1,"")
```

in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="fail",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down

In **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down

Here is a sample:

[image: sample]